Error fetching blob in huggingface endpoints API
I'm new to using the huggingface.js api, my project was previously built with the openAI GPT API so I assume there are a lot of changes that I need to make in order to work with huggingface.js.
This is my current function that has replaced postChatGPTMessage:
const postHFMessage = async (contextMessage, conversation) => {
    // build the conversation for context
    const { textGeneration } = await import('@huggingface/inference');
    
    // Prepare the payload for the text generation request
    const payload = {
        inputs: contextMessage,
        parameters: {
            max_length: 100,
            temperature: 0.1,
            // Add any other parameters as needed
            },
        };

    // Call the textGeneration function with your payload
    try {
        const response = await textGeneration({
            accessToken: process.env.HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY,
            model: USED_MODEL,
            inputs: payload.inputs,
            parameters: payload.parameters,
        });
        if (response) {
            const responseData = await response.json();
            console.log('Received response:', responseData);
            return response;
        }
        else {
            console.log("no response from textGeneration");
        }
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log("Could not get response from textGeneration: ", error);
    }
};

HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY is a user access token (free one for reading) and the USED_MODEL is a model name that I got from the huggingface website, and I get this error when I try to use it:
Could not get response from textGeneration:  Error: An error occurred while fetching the blob
    at request (file:///Users/o*******/node_modules/@huggingface/inference/dist/index.js:207:11)

Do I need to transform the entire json parameter that I'm sending to the function to a blob before sending it? Or is the error occurring because I'm not handling the response as needed?
Looked for solutions in the huggingface.js documentation but could not conclude what was causing the problem.
